# ob_start(); callback function

Tags: php

Is there any difference (performance or otherwise) to use ob_start in the following ways?

Option 1:

```
function ob_handle($buffer){/*do something, and return buffer*/}
ob_start('ob_handle');
```

Option 2:

```
ob_start(function($buffer){/*do something, and return buffer*/});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Option 2 doesn't work before PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's hardly a difference performance-wise. It's just a matter of how the callback function is declared, it doesn't change anything about how the function is used or executed. If you want to know for sure, *benchmark it*.

The only difference is that in the first case you're declaring a global function `ob_handle`, which you can use again from elsewhere and which takes up the global name `ob_handle`. In the second case, you cannot refer to the anonymous function from elsewhere again.

Comment: Thank you, I figured as much.